# Why has xts.index stopped working after upgrading to R 4.0.0?

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I have a large body of code using xts objects, everything works fine with upgrade to R 4.0.0, but the index function has now failed.

If I run a simple script:

```
> class(SPY)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> require(quantmod)
> 
> getSymbols("SPY")
[1] "SPY"
> 
> class(SPY)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> 
> index(SPY)
Error in if (type == "Date" || type == "yearmon" || type == "yearqtr") temp = as.Date(temp) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

...However, if I run 
index(as.zoo(SPY)) --> it returns the index of dates as expected.

It appears that whatever version of index is being matched to, it is failing to pull the indexCLASS value from an XTS object.

Anybody have any idea what is wrong? I have wrapped index in a function that calls zoo.index, but this is a total hack and not correct.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rugarch_1.4-2   Quandl_2.10.0   lubridate_1.7.8 quantmod_0.4.17 TTR_0.23-6      xts_0.12-0      zoo_1.8-8      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6                MASS_7.3-51.5               mclust_5.4.6                lattice_0.20-41            
 [5] R6_2.4.1                    Rsolnp_1.16                 httr_1.4.1                  GeneralizedHyperbolic_0.8-4
 [9] tools_4.0.0                 SkewHyperbolic_0.4-0        spd_2.0-1                   grid_4.0.0                 
[13] KernSmooth_2.23-16          numDeriv_2016.8-1.1         Matrix_1.2-18               nloptr_1.2.2.1             
[17] DistributionUtils_0.6-0     ks_1.11.7                   curl_4.3                    compiler_4.0.0             
[21] generics_0.0.2              expm_0.999-4                jsonlite_1.6.1              truncnorm_1.0-8            
[25] mvtnorm_1.1-0
```

Comment: Not clear.  I am using R 4.0 and it is working fine with `packageVersion('xts')#
[1] ‘0.12.0’` `head(index(SPY))#
[1] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10"`

Comment: Thanks. Same version. Does not work for me - any idea how I would debug this? I am happy to try and post results back.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: I added it - so sorry I haven't a clue (yet) how to manage the formatting, but the info is there. Thanks for any help.

Comment: @doug_hohner Have you figured out? I'm having same issue under R 3.6.3, quantmod 0.4.17, xts 0.12.1, zoo 1.8-8. Well, I'm using some codes I ported from web

Answer (score 0):

Current xts code does not have the following line that errors, and it has never existed historically.

```
if (type == "Date" || type == "yearmon" || type == "yearqtr") temp = as.Date(temp)
```

So my best guess is that you have a function `index.xts()` in your global environment that contains the line of code that errors.

You mention the `indexCLASS` attribute, which was removed in xts 0.12.0. So the function that masks `index.xts()` likely has `type <- attr(x, "indexCLASS")` instead of using the `indexClass()` (deprecated) or (the preferred) `tclass()` function.